# add class name using javascript

Tags: javascript

How to add class on a textbox if its empty? I am using getmdl.io framework. What I want to do is when the textbox is empty I want to add a class which is (is-focused, is-invalid and is-dirty)

```
<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label" id="fn">
     <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname" autocomplete="off">
     <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="fullname">Full name</label>
</div>
```

and this is my javascript code when the submit button is click.

```
function validate () {
    var f = _('fullname').value;
    if (f == "") {
        _('fn').className += " is-invalid";
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `_`? An external library?

Comment: _() function return getElementById(element)

Comment: This is trivial. `_('foo').className = x`.  It seems maybe the issue is knowing the right time to add the class, but your question doesn't explain when that would be.

Comment: I don't understand. You add class `is-focused` but then check `f` is empty, then add it again?

Comment: @AndrewLi it supposed to be `is-invalid`